# JavaScript (ECMAScript 5) Tutorial

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I hear that ECMAScript 5 is now getting supported by most of the latest browsers.  Are there any good tutorials out there?  I tried looking myself but I didn't find anything.  Is the ES5 documentation the only thing out there?  I mainly want to know what has been depreciated in the new standard.  If I avoid these i can feel right at home when I move to ES5 and I wont miss anything depreciated.

Comment: i think it is still good to learn the current standard, because, most of the new features (at least those that i used so far) requires you to have a greater knowledge of the language, and programming in general. Try this Book, New perspective on Javascript and Ajax (2010) by Patrick carey. Should get you started

Comment: Actually there are not *so* many new things. Just some handy array and object functions. And `"use strict";`. It is more important to learn the general concepts and how to deal with functions (it's about functions in JS, isn't it ;))

Comment: If your target is the general web, you can't write exclusively for ES5 yet, and maybe not for many years, so you must learn ES3. Even though "all the latest browsers support it", not many actually use the latest browser. e.g. IE 9 only has about 3% use share and some companies *still* mandate IE 6 for their SOE. From a practical viewpoint, code written for ES3 will always work in browsers that support ES5, but not vice versa if any ES5 features are used.

Comment: The book "New perspective on Javascript and Ajax (2010) by Patrick carey" has bad ratings from 1 to 2 stars on Amazon, Barnes and Nobles, and a few others when I checked.  I will just learn the current standard, but I would like to know what is depreciated in the new standard so I can move over to ES5 (JS 1.8.5) easily in the future.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The new (2011) edition of "Javascript: The Definitive Guide" covers ECMAScript 5 functions thoroughly, and shows how to implement ECMAScript 3 equivalents in many cases :-)

Answer (score 9):

Referring to [ECMAScript 5 compatibility table](http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/) page, Firefox 4 - 6 and Chrome 13 - 14 are the most compatible browsers.

The [Mozilla JavaScript Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript) might be the closest. See its [entry](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/JavaScript/ECMAScript_5_support_in_Mozilla) for ECMAScript5 support for details.

**Update (2011-08-05)**

It appears that ES5 is backward compatible with ES3 ([1](http://www.novogeek.com/post/2011/04/25/ECMAScript-5-Strict-mode-support-in-browsers-What-does-this-mean.aspx), [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Features)). The only way to break the compatibility is to use "use strict" to enable a subset of ES5 deemed as less error prone.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Sadly, I cant find a list of features that have been depreciated as of ES5 only what is new.

Answer (score 2):

The features that have been deprecated are the features that are disabled when the "use strict" mode is initiated (a rather poor way of doing it, IMO, since it requires them to come up with new terminology for the next version... but I digress).

I found Resig's article on this rather useful, although I haven't verified anything he says here: 
http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/